# Laravel 5 - TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 67

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to upload a video and images through a form using **Laravel 5.2**

When uploading just images it works without any problems, however when I try to upload the video as well it just throws the **TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 67** error.

My form does have the hidden csrf_field **{!! csrf_field() !!}** and my routes are inside **Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () { }**

I just cannot figure out why this isn't working.

**Form:**

```
    <form action="{{ url('admin-backend/video') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {!! csrf_field() !!}
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Name">
        <textarea name="description" class="form-control" rows="8"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
        <input type="file" class="form-control" name="video" />
        <input type="file" class="form-control" name="feature_image" />
        <input type="file" class="form-control" name="image_1" />
        <input type="file" class="form-control" name="image_2" />
        <input type="file" class="form-control" name="image_3" />
        <input type="file" class="form-control" name="image_4" />
        <input type="file" class="form-control" name="image_5" />
        <input type="file" class="form-control" name="image_6" />
    </form>
```

**Routes:**

```
 Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::get('/admin-backend', function () {
        return view('backend.admin.index');
    });

    Route::get('/admin-backend/video', 'adminVideoController@index');
    Route::get('/admin-backend/video/create', 'adminVideoController@create');
    Route::post('/admin-backend/video', 'adminVideoController@store');
    Route::get('/admin-backend/video/{id}', 'adminVideoController@show');
    Route::get('/admin-backend/video/{id}/edit', 'adminVideoController@edit');
    Route::put('/admin-backend/video/{id}', 'adminVideoController@update');
});
```

**Controller store() method:**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    $fields = Video::prepareVideoUpload($request);

    $video = Video::create($fields);

    return view('backend.admin.videos.create');

}
```

**Video model:**

```
protected $table = 'videos';

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'name','description','feature_image','image_1','image_2','image_3','image_4','image_5','image_6','video','created_at','updated_at'
];


/**
 * @param $request
 * @return array
 *
 * This function prepares the video upload by placing all relevant data into the $fields array.
 * It creates the necessary folder structure to place the images and video for each shoot
 *
 */
public static function prepareVideoUpload($request)
{
    $fields = []; //This will be used to store the information in the database instead of request
    $fields['name'] = $request['name'];
    $fields['description'] = $request['description'];


    $videoPath = public_path() . '/videos/' . substr(date("Y/m/d"),0,7); // videoPath looks like - /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/website/public/videos/2016/04
    $name = str_replace(' ', '-', $request['name']);
    $newVideoPath = $videoPath . '/' . $name;


    //if the folder is already created just make the new video name folder
    if( is_dir( $videoPath ) ) {
        mkdir($newVideoPath);
    }else{
        //create the folder structure /year/month/video-name
        mkdir($newVideoPath, 0777, true);
    }


    //Create the video and images folders for the individual shoot
    mkdir($newVideoPath . '/video');
    mkdir($newVideoPath . '/images');


    //If the video was uploaded successfully, move it to the images directory
    if ($request->hasFile('video') && $request->file('video')->isValid()) {
        $request->file('video')->move($newVideoPath . '/video',$request->file('video')->getClientOriginalName());
        $fields['video'] = 'videos/' . substr(date("Y/m/d"),0,7) . '/' . $name . '/video/' . $request->file('video')->getClientOriginalName();
    }


    //If the feature image was uploaded successfully, move it to the images directory
    if ($request->hasFile('feature_image') && $request->file('feature_image')->isValid()) {
        $request->file('feature_image')->move($newVideoPath . '/images',$request->file('feature_image')->getClientOriginalName());
        $fields['feature_image'] = 'videos/' . substr(date("Y/m/d"),0,7) . '/' . $name . '/images/' . $request->file('feature_image')->getClientOriginalName();

    }


    for($i=1;$i < 7; $i++){
        //If the image was uploaded successfully, move it to the images directory
        if ($request->hasFile('image_' . $i) && $request->file('image_' . $i)->isValid()) {
            $request->file('image_' . $i)->move($newVideoPath . '/images',$request->file('image_' . $i)->getClientOriginalName());
            $fields['image_' . $i] = 'videos/' . substr(date("Y/m/d"),0,7) . '/' . $name . '/images/' . $request->file('image_' . $i)->getClientOriginalName();
        }
    }

    return $fields;

}
```

I haven't done any validation as of yet, so when I try the upload without the video it works and saves to the folder and outs the folder path into the database. However when i try to upload video with it, then it throws the error.

Im a little stuck here, does any one have any ideas?

Comment: Do you have unique APP_KEY generated and saved in your .env file? Also try php artisan dump-autoload

Comment: What is your config/session.php `driver` value? If it's file, be sure `files` in the same file has the correct path,

Comment: Yes app_key is generated in .env file and dump autoload dit nothing

Comment: what is the correct pat for files?

Comment: 'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),

Comment: Yes thats the one i have got

Comment: Check for 'path' => '/' too

Answer (score 2):

My guess is you are hitting a max size limit on POST data, which is causing it to just drop the inputs.

You can adjust your webserver and php to a higher limit and see if it helps.

`post_max_size` in php.ini  would be a good place to start.